# Passing an array to more than one view from one controller ? Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a question about how to pass an array to more than one view from one controller in Laravel 5, is it even possible ? I want to pass an array to index.blade.php and to home.blade.php from one function index(). The index page will show all of the data while the home page will only show a few. Here are the code below

Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\EdisiRequest;
use App\Edisi;
use Session;
use Storage;

class EdisiController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $edisi_list = Edisi::all();
        return view('edisi/index', compact('edisi_list'));
    }
}
```

home.blade.php

```
@extends('template')

@section('main')
<div class="container sitecontainer bgw">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 m22 single-post">
            @if (count($edisi_list) > 0)
            <div class="reviewlist review-posts">
                <?php foreach ($edisi_list as $edisi): ?>
                    <div class="post-review col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="post-media entry">
                            <a href="#" title="">
                                <img src="{{ asset('fotoupload/' . $edisi->cover) }}" alt="fotoupload/coveredisi.png" class="img-responsive" style="height: 480px; width: 1200px;">
                            </a>
                        </div><!-- end media -->
                        <div class="post-title">
                            <h4 style="text-align: center;"><a href="#">{{ $edisi->judul }}</a></h4>
                        </div><!-- end post-title -->
                    </div><!-- end post-review -->
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </div><!-- end review-posts -->
            @else
            <p>Tidak ada data edisi.</p>
            @endif
        </div><!-- end col -->
    </div><!-- end row -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="pagination-wrapper text-center">
            <nav>
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- end container -->
@stop
```

index.blade.php

```
@extends('template')

@section('main')
<div class="container sitecontainer bgw">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 m22 single-post">
                <div id="siswa">
                <h2>Daftar Edisi</h2>

                @if (count($edisi_list) > 0)
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Judul</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach ($edisi_list as $edisi): ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $edisi->judul }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="box-button">
                                        {{ link_to('edisi/' . $edisi->id, 'Detail', ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-sm']) }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="box-button">
                                        {{ link_to('edisi/' . $edisi->id . '/edit', 'Edit', ['class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-sm']) }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="box-button">
                                        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'action' => ['EdisiController@destroy', $edisi->id]]) !!}
                                        {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm']) !!}
                                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                @else
                <p>Tidak ada data edisi.</p>
                @endif

                <div class="tombol-nav">
                    <a href="edisi/create" class="btn btn-primary">Tambah Edisi</a>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- / #jurnal -->
        </div><!-- end col -->
    </div><!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end container -->
@stop
```

I tried by making another controller for the home page, but still not working, it always show error "$edisi_list undefined variable". If there is another way to that please show me, thank you!

EdisiServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Edisi;

class EdisiServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot() {
        View::composer(['edisi/index', 'pages/home'], function ($view) {
            $edisi_list = Edisi::all();
            $view->with('edisi_list', $edisi_list);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register() {
        //
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers) to do that:

```
 View::composer(['index', 'home'], function ($view) {
    $edisi_list = Edisi::all();
    $view->with('edisi_list', $edisi_list);
 });
```

Comment: By using this so I need to make a new service provider ? pardon me, but where to put this code ? @alexey

Comment: Yes, you should create a service provider, you will find example code by following link above. If you don't want to use closure, you will also need to create view composer class.

Comment: mm hey, may I ask you again ? I did making the service provider using the code you gave above, but it shows me a new error "FatalErrorException in EdisiServiceProvider.php line 16: Class 'App\Providers\View' not found". I did register the service provider to config/app.php @alexey

Comment: I've updated the question showing the service provider code

Comment: Add `use View;` to other `use` clauses. Or do `\View::` instead of `View::` in the code.

Comment: Added the "use view" and it's working now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else passing arrays with view composer, passing it using `compact` won't work.
You'll have to directly send it:

***In the custom composer (in my case `app/Http/View/Composers/UserInfoComposer.php`)***

```
public function compose( View $view ) {

    $allUserInfo = array();

    $generalFunctions      = new GeneralFunctions();
    $currentUserID         = $generalFunctions->getCurrentUserID();
    $currentUserName       = $generalFunctions->getCurrentUserName();
    $currentUserEmail      = $generalFunctions->getCurrentUserEmail();
    $currentUserProfilePic = $generalFunctions->getCurrentProfilePic();

    $allUserInfo['currentUserID']         = $currentUserID;
    $allUserInfo['currentUserName']       = $currentUserName;
    $allUserInfo['currentUserEmail']      = $currentUserEmail;
    $allUserInfo['currentUserProfilePic'] = $currentUserProfilePic;

    $view->with( 'allUserInfo', $allUserInfo );
//NOT: $view->with( 'allUserInfo', compact('allUserInfo'));

}
```

Reference for creating view composers: [LINK](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers)